# POST request using jquery not successful

Tags: jquery, ajax

Before jumping to marking this as duplicate, please hear me out. I have a server hosted on `https://` that serves POST requests. I have to make a call for testing purpose from my stub. I used to do it using `<form>` and `<action>` and it worked great but now we have implemented a filter which takes the headers and the request is dropped if header is not found. AFAIK there is no way to add headers in a simple html form, so I tried to use jquery but failed miserably and the only thing I can see in Network of Chrome Dev window is pending (probably because of https:). I did using `$.ajax` and `$.post` with similar failure. Now I am trying to just hit a post request to servlet using `$.post` but even that is not happening (happens with `<form>`). This is a snippet which I am using right now.

```
var url:"https://hostname/XXXXXX";
$.post( url, { param1: "par", param2: "par" }, function( data ) {
  $( "#demo" ).html( data );
});
```

what am I probably missing.

Comment: the error message? if any ? look at the browser console

Comment: no error on console. the code is clean. in Network it shows status:pending, initiator: jquery.min.js:4.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting data from server in form of JSON, you can try below code:

```
var postUrl:"https://hostname/XXXXXX";
 var modelData = new Object({ param1: "par", param2: "par"});

    $.ajax({
        url: postUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: modelData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $( "#demo" ).html( data );
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) { }
    });
```

Comment: not json. those are simple parameters unrelated to each other

Answer (score 0):

It's Works..!

```
    var url:"https://hostname/XXXXXX";
    $.post( url, { param1: "par", param2: "par" })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $( "#demo" ).html( data );
    });
```

Comment: did not work. its same as before. It has to be related to https:// because localhost requests work well